# homomorphism between cohomology induced by the multiplication of an H-space

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

Define the product on $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ in the following way:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi:\mathbb{C}P\overset{\Delta}\longrightarrow(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)^k\overset{\mu}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}P^\infty,\\
y\mapsto (y,y,\cdots,y)\mapsto y^k.
\end{eqnarray*}
Here $\Delta$ is the $k$-diagonal map and $\mu$ the multiplication given on Hatcher's book algebraic topology page 282.

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi^*: H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z})&\to& H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}),\\
\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]&\to& \mathbb{Z}[\alpha].
\end{eqnarray*}

What is $\phi^*\alpha$? How to compute?

And
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_*: H_*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z})&\to& H_*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}),\\
\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]&\to& \Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[\alpha].
\end{eqnarray*}

What is $\phi_*\alpha$? How to compute?

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to know the comultiplication induced by $\mu$ on cohomology. For degree reasons the unique possibility is

$$\Delta(\alpha) = \alpha \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \alpha$$

and from here you are in the realm of a purely Hopf-algebraic calculation: you want to apply the "$n^{th}$ comultiplication" $\Delta_n : H \to H^{\otimes n}$ (where $H$ is the Hopf algebra in question, here the cohomology) and then apply the "$n^{th}$ multiplication" $m_n : H^{\otimes n} \to H$. By $m_n$ I mean the operation

$$\alpha_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \alpha_n \mapsto \alpha_1 \dots \alpha_n$$

and by $\Delta_n$ I mean the dual thing. The result is called the $n^{th}$ *Adams operation* $\psi_n$ and can be computed in this case as follows. We have

$$\Delta_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^n 1 \otimes \dots \otimes \alpha \otimes \dots \otimes 1$$

where in the $k^{th}$ term $\alpha$ appears in the $k^{th}$ position, and hence

$$\psi_n(\alpha) = m_n \Delta_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha = n \alpha.$$

The Adams operations are all ring homomorphisms, so this uniquely determines $\psi_n$ on the entire cohomology ring. The computation for homology is dual to this one.